# How can I resolve the error sonar scanner ERROR: Project 'my:project' can't have 2 modules with the following key: my:project:my:project ERROR:

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, properties-file

When I gave the analysis properties directly in the "Analysis Parameters" section of Excecute sonar scanner in Jenkins, its working fine.
But when I put the same properties in to a file sonar-project.properties and trying to call the file for execution its throwing error

```
sonar.userHome=mydir/sonar_cache
sonar.projectBaseDir=mydir/project/
sonar.working.directory=mydir/project//sonar
sonar.scm.disabled=false
sonar.scm.provider=git

sonar.projectKey=my:project
sonar.projectName=Project
sonar.projectVersion=91
sonar.host.url=https://onesonarcloud.vpc.com/
sonar.login=-------

sonar.includePlugins=views,report,buildbreaker
sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.log.level=INFO
sonar.analysis.mode=publish
sonar.skipDesign=true

#sonar build breaker report processing time
sonar.buildbreaker.queryMaxAttempts=3000
sonar.buildbreaker.queryInterval=30000
sonar.buildbreaker.skip=false 
sonar.timemachine.period1 = 'previous_analysis'  
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.exclusions=**/*.css,**/*.sql,**/*.js,**/*.htm,**/*.html,**/*.jsp,**/model/*,**ws-clients/ws/*,**/provctl/broker/*java,Shared-persistence/src/com/verizon/pc/persistence/entity/*java,**/prism/ade/brokers/*java,**/prism/brokers/db/db2/*java, **/prism/localaccess/brokers/*java


sonar.modules=MODULE1,MODULE2

#MODULE1 MODULE SETTINGS
MODULE1.sonar.projectKey=MODULE1
MODULE1.sonar.projectName=MODULE1
MODULE1.sonar.projectBaseDir=mydir/project/
MODULE1.sonar.sources=/ProvisionController/module1/src
MODULE1.sonar.surefire.reportsPath=testing/build_tests/provctl/reports
MODULE1.sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco_provctl.exec
MODULE1.sonar.junit.reportsPath=testing/build_tests/provctl/reports
MODULE1.sonar.tests=/ProvisionController/module1/test
MODULE1.sonar.java.tests=/ProvisionController/module1/test
MODULE1.sonar.java.binaries=/**/build
MODULE1.sonar.java.libraries=/ProvisionController/ProvisionController/EarContent/APP-INF/lib/*.jar,buildtools/lib_test/*.jar,vzthirdparty/lib/*jar,/Common/**/*jar,/ws-clients/**/*jar,/Logging/**/*jar,/apps/opt/weblogic/weblogic121mp3/wlserver/**/*.jar
MODULE1.sonar.java.test.binaries=testing/build_tests/common-core,testing/build_tests/provctl
MODULE1.sonar.java.test.libraries=/ProvisionController/ProvisionController/EarContent/APP-INF/lib/*.jar,buildtools/lib_test/*.jar,vzthirdparty/lib/*jar,/Common/**/*jar,/ws-clients/**/*jar,/Logging/**/*jar,/apps/opt/weblogic/weblogic121mp3/wlserver/**/*.jar
#MODULE2 MODULE SETTINGS
MODULE2.sonar.projectKey=MODULE2
MODULE2.sonar.projectName=MODULE2
MODULE2.sonar.projectBaseDir=mydir/project/
MODULE2.sonar.sources=/ProvisionController/module2/src
MODULE2.sonar.surefire.reportsPath=testing/build_tests/prism/reports
MODULE2.sonar.jacoco.reportPath=testing/build_tests/prism/jacoco_prism.exec
MODULE2.sonar.junit.reportsPath=testing/build_tests/prism/reports
MODULE2.sonar.tests=/ProvisionController/module2/test
MODULE2.sonar.java.tests=/ProvisionController/module2/test
MODULE2.sonar.java.binaries=/**/build
MODULE2.sonar.java.libraries=/ProvisionController/ProvisionController/EarContent/APP-INF/lib/*.jar,buildtools/lib_test/*.jar,vzthirdparty/lib/*jar,/Common/**/*jar,/ws-clients/**/*jar,/Logging/**/*jar,/apps/opt/weblogic/weblogic121mp3/wlserver/**/*.jar
MODULE2.sonar.java.test.binaries=testing/build_tests/prism
MODULE2.sonar.java.test.libraries=/ProvisionController/ProvisionController/EarContent/APP-INF/lib/*.jar,buildtools/lib_test/*.jar,vzthirdparty/lib/*jar,/Common/**/*jar,/ws-clients/**/*jar,/Logging/**/*jar,/apps/opt/weblogic/weblogic121mp3/wlserver/**/*.jar
```

> INFO: Project root configuration file: /mydir/sonar-project.properties
> INFO: Analyzing on SonarCloud INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source
> code encoding: "UTF-8" WARN: SonarScanner will require Java 11 to run
> starting in SonarQube 8.x INFO: Load global settings INFO: Load global
> settings (done) | time=5588ms INFO: Server id:
> 5CD06320-AXMqH8ooQ9pWqCaUna0x INFO: User cache:
> mydir/sonar_cache/cache INFO: Load/download plugins INFO: Load plugins
> index INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=176ms INFO: Load/download
> plugins (done) | time=13541ms INFO: Loaded core extensions:
> developer-scanner INFO: Process project properties INFO:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE INFO:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: Total time: 30.493s INFO: Final Memory: 32M/471M INFO:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution ERROR: Project 'my:project'
> can't have 2 modules with the following key: my:project:my:project
> ERROR:  ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full
> debug logging. WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the
> workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeeded? ERROR: SonarQube scanner
> exited with non-zero code: 2 Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Could you please paste the whole error log

Comment: And if java, what is your pom Group/Artifact and module structure? That should be your project key.